# How to typesafely override the class defined inside flutter package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an auth package in my Flutter app that defines the `BaseUser` class. The `BaseUser` class provides the basic structure for a `User` class which is defined inside an app. Here is how the `BaseUser` class looks:

```
class BaseUser {
  final String id;
  final String email;

  BaseUser({ required this.id, required this.email });
}
```

In addition to the `BaseUser` class, my package also defines UserAPIService which make login, signup, etc. requests.

```
class UserAPIService extends BaseAPIService {
  Future<LoginResponse> login({ required String email, required String password }) async {
    final response = await api.login(email, password);

    LoginResponse loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJSON(response);

    return loginResponse;
  }
}
```

This is how `LoginResponse` looks like:

```
class LoginResponse {
  final BaseUser user;
  
  factory LoginRespionse.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic>) {
    // Error handle logic...

    return LoginResponse(
      user: BaseUser(email: json['user']['email'], id: json['user']['id']);
    );
  }
}
```

BaseAPIService is a simple abstract class containing the function declarations for login, signup, etc.

All these services are used in the `AuthenticationRepository` inside the app, somehow like this:

```
class AuthenticationRepository {
  Future<LoginResponse> login(String email, password) {
    final response = userApiService.login(email, password);

    return response;
  }
}
```

This is the `User` class defined inside the app:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
  final String? fullName;

  User({
    required super.email,
    required super.id,
    this.fullName,
  });
  
  // Named constructors and other methods...

}
```

**PROBLEM:** How can I make the user class defined inside the app type compatible with the BaseUser which is defined in `LoginResponse` class?

Also, Is it possible to somehow inject the User class in the LoginResponse class so that the named constructor of the `User` class is called when parsing the user?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create a Use Case

```
class UserUseCase {
  User convertLoginResponseToUser(LoginResponse loginResponse) {
    return User(id: loginResponse.user.id, email: loginResponse.user.email, fullName: null);
  }
}
```

Then in your class that call AuthenticationRepository

```
Future<User> login(String email, password) async {
    final response = await authenticationRepository.login(email, password);
    return userUseCase.convertLoginResponseToUser(response);
  }
```

If LoginResponse is in external package, it should not know about your User

```
BaseUser = Data Layer
AuthenticationRepository = Data Layer
User = Domain Layer (Entity)
UserUseCase = Domain Layer (Use Case)
```

Comment: This can be one way, but I was wondering if I can achieve this somehow using generics.

Comment: @SudeepBashistha You cannot generically invoke constructors or `static` methods.  If you require `LoginResponse` to construct a class that derives from `BaseUser`, then you will need to plumb a callback through to invoke the derived constructor.